# Using boost's socket.async_send_to()

Tags: sockets, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I've been stuck on this for a while now. I am trying to send the following:

`boost::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]> m_data`

over the wire using:

```
_socket.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(m_data), m_remote_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&UDPServer::handle_send, this, message,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

I get the error "no instance of overloaded function boost::asio::buffer matches the argument list `boost::shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>`"

m_data is filled in another function.

I suspect this is because I actually have to use the key word new on m_data. But I can't quite figure out how to do it. I've tried a few different variations.  Can anybody offer me some insight here? This is probably more a question of how to dereference a shared pointer then anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost::asio::buffer has an impressive lists of consttructors, but neither of them takes `shared_ptr<[]>` (possibly an oversight form lib authors).

In your case, you simply need to derefence shared ptr, for example, by calling get on it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! So I should call get as in m_data.get ()?

Comment: What the issue ended up being was we had the size of our data wrong. When using async_end_to, you give it a pointer to the beginning of the data (m_data.get()) and then the size. Thank you for your help!